# Strange behaviour difference between terminal and bash script for python module

Tags: python, bash, systemd

I installed a python script for updating my dyndns record for my nextcloudpi:
https://github.com/Domain-Connect/DomainConnectDDNS-Python
When i run the program from the terminal by using `domain-connect-dyndns update --all` it works out well.
Now i created a systemd service and a timer calling the service. The service is calling a very simple bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash

/home/pi/.local/bin/domain-connect-dyndns update --all
```

when i check the execution of the service it turns out like that:

```
pi@nextcloudpi:~ $ systemctl status ddns.service
● ddns.service - Update IONOS DNS Record
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ddns.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-10-18 20:20:10 BST; 45s ago
  Process: 18391 ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/pi/own-bashscripts/execddns.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 18391 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 18 20:20:06 nextcloudpi systemd[1]: Started Update IONOS DNS Record.
Oct 18 20:20:10 nextcloudpi bash[18391]: Couldn't read setttings.
Oct 18 20:20:10 nextcloudpi bash[18391]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Oct 18 20:20:10 nextcloudpi bash[18391]:   File "/home/pi/.local/bin/domain-connect-dyndns", line 10, in <module>
Oct 18 20:20:10 nextcloudpi bash[18391]:     sys.exit(main())
Oct 18 20:20:10 nextcloudpi bash[18391]:   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dyndns/command_line.py
Oct 18 20:20:10 nextcloudpi bash[18391]:     domains = config.keys()
Oct 18 20:20:10 nextcloudpi bash[18391]: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'config' referenced before assignment
Oct 18 20:20:10 nextcloudpi systemd[1]: ddns.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 18 20:20:10 nextcloudpi systemd[1]: ddns.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Can anybody tell me what i'm missing? Why, that python issue is occuring only when i call it with the script, and everything is working when i execute it from the terminal?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script cannot find `settings.py`. You need to set `WorkingDirectory` config in service configuration file or provide path to settings in the script parameters:

```sh
# don't forget to change the path
domain-connect-dyndns update --all --config /home/pi/ddnsdir/settings.txt
```

Comment: yay, that did the trick, looks like everything is working now properly like it should be. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your environment. When you use a terminal you have a special environment. To see what is in your environment you could run:

```
env | less
```

When systemd starts your script it uses a different environment. To check it, pipe your env from the script to a logfile. It could be a expanded $PATH or another exported variable which is missing in the script-env.